# MvRX DrawerLayout + generally more examples wanted

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout, rx-kotlin, epoxy

I'm trying to set up a DrawerLayout in the MvRx sample project but i am kind of stuck.

Totally new to both epoxy and MvRx in general and i have been playing around for a week now learning about the framework and testing components i need to convert our app to MvRx.

**What i am wondering is how you setup a DrawerLayout view using MvRx.**

Also the current examples are very comprehensive for noobs. Anyone has a minimalist starter available?

// JQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question you're really trying to ask is how to set up drawer layout with epoxy, since MvRx has nothing to do with layouts, but it's actually used for state management.

Epoxy makes it easy to setup dynamic views, and scrolling screens but for all of the stuff like toolbars, bottom navigation views, drawers etc. you need to set it up exactly the same as before.

What I usually do in my projects is set up a drawer layout in activity and frame layout for my fragments and all of my fragments have only one EpoxyRecyclerView in them and I just insert them into the frame layout of my activity upon a click from navigation drawer.